# SQL Server 2016: Import of JSON Information

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I operate a SQL Server 2016 to store different information that I receive via REST/JSON. This works properly good and i actually add additional sources (4 Import types). On one json import i got an error like that:

> Msg 13609, Level 16, Status 4, line 2
>   The JSON text is not properly formatted. At position 0, the unexpected character  "൛ " was found.

I checked the file and Syntax and they are similar like other files / Formats that I Import (without an error):

Json example:

```
[
  {
    "cid": 6498,
    "hotel_description": "Hotelmerkmale: All Inclusive, Family, Paare, Single\n<br /> \n<br /> Die ideale Wahl f&uuml;r den unternehmungslustigen Gast. Genie&szlig;en Sie tags&uuml;ber vom Pool den entspannenden Blick auf das Meer und die Side-Halbinsel und leben Sie abends Ihr Shopping- oder Tanzfieber in der nahe gelegenen Altstadt von Side aus.\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Lage:</strong> In erh&ouml;hter Lage mit Panoramablick auf das Meer und die historische Altstadt von Side. Ca. 200 m vom kilometerlangen, flach abfallenden, feinen Sandstrand und ca. 1,5 km vom Zentrum mit zahlreichen Einkaufs- und Unterhaltungsm&ouml;glichkeiten, Restaurants, Bars und Caf&eacute;s entfernt (regelm&auml;&szlig;ige Minibusverbindungen vorhanden).\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Ausstattung:</strong> Bekanntes Hotel der gehobenen Mittelklasse mit 2 Swimmingpools (einer davon mit 2 Wasserrutschen), Sonnenterrasse. Liegen, Auflagen, Sonnenschirme (Badet&uuml;cher gegen Kaution). Pool-/Snackbar, Strandbar. Elegante Empfangshalle, Rezeption, WLAN in der Lobby, Sitzgruppen, Lobbybar, Spieleraum, Fernsehecke mit Gro&szlig;bildschirm, klimatisiertes Hauptrestaurant, 4 &Agrave;-la-carte-Restaurants, Minimarkt, Diskothek, Friseur, Hallenbad. Landeskategorie: 5 Sterne, 341 Zimmer, 6 Etagen, Lifte.\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Wohnen:</strong> Doppelzimmer (ca. 18-22 qm), Klimaanlage (indiv.), Minibar, Telefon, TV, Mietsafe, Kaffee-/Teeset. Dusche/WC mit F&ouml;hn. Balkon. Max. 2E. Wahlweise seitl. Meerblick/Meerblick. Max. 3E, auch zur Alleinnutzung buchbar\n<br /> Juniorsuite (ca. 35 qm), zus. Couch, Klimaanlage (indiv.), Minibar, Telefon, TV, Mietsafe, Kaffee-/Teeset. Dusche/WC mit F&ouml;hn. Balkon. Landseite/seitl. Meerblick. Max. 3E+1K\n<br /> Familienzimmer (ca. 40 qm), zus. separates Schlafzimmer, Klimaanlage (indiv.), Minibar, Telefon, TV, Mietsafe, Kaffee-/Teeset. Dusche/WC mit F&ouml;hn. Balkon. Meerseite/seitl. Meerblick. Max. 4E\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Essen und Trinken:</strong> all inclusive: Fr&uuml;hst&uuml;cksbuffet, mittags und abends kaltes/warmes Buffet, Themenabende, t&auml;glich Showkochen\n<br /> Snacks (stdw.), nachm. Kaffee, Tee, Geb&auml;ck\n<br /> Alkoholfr., nat. alkohol. (ab 18 J.) Getr&auml;nke von 10:00-24:00 Uhr (an der Strandbar von 10:00-17:00 Uhr)T&auml;gliche Auff&uuml;llung der Minibar mit Wasser\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Wellness und Fitness:</strong> Wellnesscenter (ca. 370 qm)\n<br /> T&uuml;rkisches Bad, Dampfbad, Sauna\n<br /> Jacuzzi, Wellnessmassagen (geg. Geb.)\n<br /> Fitnessraum (ca. 70 qm)\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Sport und Fitness:</strong> Tischtennis\n<br /> Wassersport am Strand (&ouml;rtlicher Anbieter, gegen Geb&uuml;hr)\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Einzelzimmer ohne Aufpreis:</strong> Zu bestimmten Terminen kein Zuschlag\n<br /> \n<strong>Single mit Kind:</strong> Kinderfestpreis bei einem Vollzahler\n<br /> \n<strong>Kinderfestpreis:</strong>2 Kinder 2-12 Jahre\n<br />\n<br /> \n<br /> \n<strong>Minis &amp; Maxis (4-12 Jahre):</strong> Miniclub (stdw.)\n<br /> Spielplatz, Kinderbuffet\n<br /> \n<br />"
  }
]
```

My SQL statement looks like this:

```
MERGE dbo.hotel_description t
USING ((SELECT
            cid, hotel_description
        FROM
            OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\Import\weg.de\hotel_info_import.json', SINGLE_NCLOB)j
        CROSS APPLY
            OPENJSON(BulkColumn)
            WITH
               (cid INT,
                hotel_description NVARCHAR(MAX)))) s ON t.cid = s.cid

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (cid, hotel_description)
    VALUES (s.cid, s.hotel_description);
```

I checked Google and stackoverflow but found no reason for that error message.
Any hints?

Thanks

Regards
Timo

Comment: This says that the *input* has a weird starting character. I'd guess you tried to read a file that begins with a BOM

Comment: [FIX: BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET import wrong data if UTF-8 encoded file does not have a BOM in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3172671/fix-bulk-insert-or-openrowset-import-wrong-data-if-utf-8-encoded-file) Have you installed any updates on your server?

Comment: Try importing the data directly into a staging table and check what the first characters are. BOM is U+FEFF.

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, found the Problem (just for info: The SQL Server 2016 is on CU7). One of your guess was a good tip. I changed the encoding of the json file from UTF8 to UCS2 and it works. I thought that this bug was fixed since CU1. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2016 CU7 still needed that the JSON file must be be encoded as Little Endian (UCS-2) or UTF8 with BOM. UTF8 without BOM runs into that error.

Comment: The server can't know what type of Unicode encoding you use unless you tell it. After all, a UTF8 file is no different than an ANSI file if you only use English characters. Try with `CODEPAGE = '65001'` which is the codepage for UTF8